# Creating a file on the SD-Card in android

Tags: android

I want to create a file on the SD-Card and later save a CSV file in it.

From surfing around I noticed that there seem to be two ways about going about it:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

> If you're using API Level 8 or
>   greater, use getExternalFilesDir() to
>   open a File that represents the
>   external storage directory where you
>   should save your files. This method
>   takes a type parameter that specifies
>   the type of subdirectory you want,
>   such as DIRECTORY_MUSIC and
>   DIRECTORY_RINGTONES (pass null to
>   receive the root of your application's
>   file directory).
>
> If you're using API Level 7 or lower,
>   use getExternalStorageDirectory(), to
>   open a File representing the root of
>   the external storage. You should then
>   write your data in the following
>   directory:
>
> /Android/data//files/

And http://www.anddev.org/working_with_files-t115.html :

```
FileWriter f = new FileWriter("/sdcard/download/possible.txt");
```

What way should I use? If the first, how do I write my application to be compatible with both API level <=7 and >=8? Is there some good tutorial for doing it the first way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well if you need compatibility with API level 7 and lower, use `getExternalStorageDirectory()` method. Also note that staring from API level 4 you have to request permission to write onto SD card:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thanks, the thing with the permission was holding me back.